# How can I set an element's display to 'block' ? (more below)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, webpack

I added a event listener to a button, which would change the css of the #popUpForm, but it only works, if I add inline css to the #popUpForm. How could I do it, If i want to set the display of the element in the css?

```js
const addBtn = document.querySelector('#addItem')

addBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('#popUpForm').style.display = 'block'
})
```

```css
#popUpForm {
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  display: none; /* change this */
}
```

```html
<input id="addItem" type="button" value="+">

<div id="popUpForm">
  Some stuff
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works. I made a snippet and it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, but I would still recommend a class

```js
const addBtn = document.querySelector('#addItem')

addBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('#popUpForm').classList.toggle("hide"); // or classList.remove("hide")
})
```

```css
#popUpForm {
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="addItem" type="button" value="+">

<div id="popUpForm" class="hide">
  Here is some stuff
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery show/hide methods:

```
$('#popUpForm').hide();
$('#popUpForm').show();
```

Or using VanilaJs:

```
const hide = (elem) => {
   elem.style.display = 'none';
 }


const show = (elem) => {
    elem.style.display = 'block';
}
 
 // usage
 // hide element

 hide(document.querySelector('#popUpForm'));

// show element

show(document.querySelector('#popUpForm'));
```